# How big is the Windows Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I was deleting old files and folders and got this:

[image]

So I thought to myself, how big is the Recycle Bin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size of the Recycle Bin is customizable.

---

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The Recycle bin is actually a folder.You can see it on C drive (or other drive if it also has recyling bin) if you enable show hidden files and show system files.If you want to you can also remove the folder.

The recycle bin on desktop is actually shortcut to real folder.

Any folder doesnt take up any disk space only its contents.So the more files it contains the "bigger" it is

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @joeqwerty im editing it